# Jbuilder not wrapping single object in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I have a index view in my rails application that allows filtering via search params. When a group op articles are returned its is wropped in an `articles` colllection like `{"articles":[{"article":{"id":341,"updated":"2015-08-18T13:05:08.427Z","title":"`. But if only a single object is found the `articles` level is missing, `{"article":{"id":398,"updated":"2015-08-07T11:37:26.200Z","title":`. How can I fix it so that a single object behaves like  multiple?

#### _articles.list.json.jbuilder

```
require 'uri'
require 'publish_on'
json.cache! ['v1', articles] do
  json.articles articles do |article|
    json.cache! ['v1', article] do
      json.article do
        json.id article.id
        json.updated as_ns_date(article.updated_at)
        json.title article.label
        json.numberOfViews article.view_mappings.count
        json.numberOfFavorites article.favorite_mappings.count
        json.imageURLs article.images if article.images.any?
        json.youtubeURL article.youtube unless article.youtube.blank?
        json.tags article.categories.map(&:label)
        json.isFeatured article.featured
        json.isPublished article.is_published
        json.published as_ns_date(article.publish_on)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### index.json.jbuilder

```
json.partial! 'articles/articles_list', articles: @articles
```

#### articles_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @articles = SearchArticlesCommand.new(params).execute
    render :index
  end
```

#### search_articles_command.rb

```
class SearchArticlesCommand
  def initialize(params = {})
    @since = params[:since_date]
    @keys = params[:search_query]
    @category = params[:category]
  end

  def execute
    Article.unscoped do
      query = if @since.present?
        Article.article.since_date(@since)
      else
        Article.published_article
      end
      query = query.search_by_keywords(@keys) if @keys.present?
      query = query.search_by_category(@category) if @category.present?
      query.select(:id, :updated_at, :label, :is_published, :featured, :slug, :created_at).order(created_at: :desc)
    end
  end
end
```

#### article.rb

```
  class Article < Comfy::Cms::Page
    include PgSearch
    include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
    HOSTNAME = ENV['HOSTNAME'] || Socket.gethostname

    has_many :view_mappings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :favorite_mappings, dependent: :destroy

    pg_search_scope :search_by_keywords, against: [:content_cache, :label], using: { tsearch: { any_word: true, prefix: true } }

    pg_search_scope :search_by_category, associated_against: {
        categories: [:label]
      }

  scope :since_date, -> (date) { where('created_at > ? OR updated_at > ? ', date, date) if date.present? }

  scope :folder, -> { where.not(layout_id: ENV['ARTICLE_LAYOUT_ID']) }

  scope :published_article, -> { published.article }

  scope :article, -> { where(layout_id: ENV['ARTICLE_LAYOUT_ID']) }
```

Comment: Can you show us the way you are fetching the `articles`?

Comment: @MurifoX I've update the question with the related controller and command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is what i suspected. If you want the same behavior your query should return the same type of object when it finds one or many articles. The problem is that either you are returning an `ActiveRecordRelation` or a `Article` object depending on your params.

```
@articles = Article.all     # => ActiveRecordRelation, an array per se
@articles = Article.find(1) # => Article object
```

When it comes to `jbuilder` to construct the `JSON` it checks if it is an array of objects and then wrap the json with a `{ keyword => array }`. WHen it is a single object, it defaults to a single object `{article: {}}`.

The solution is simple, you can tweak your `SearchArticlesCommand` to always return an `ActiveRecordRelation`, even if it finds only one object.

Comment: Should I use `Array#wrap` is is there a more rails idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: The `where` method always return a relation. Try dumping the use of select too. Return all values then treat then on jbuilder.

Comment: I changes the last line in the search command to `query.where.not(id: nil).order(created_at: :desc)` but it still return the same

Comment: Then the problem is inside `since_date` and `published_article` methods, as query is set to them before.

Comment: This: `scope :published_article, -> { published.article }`, i don't know about your business rules, but i think this will always return a sole object. Can't you turn this in a `where` query?

Comment: I was trying to reuse the existing scopes, bad idea?

Comment: No no, it's a great idea to reuse scopes. But it is getting in the way of your problem here. Maybe you should create one specific to the JSON rendering thing. One that always returns an relation, then you will have no problems.

Comment: Modifying the scope didn't work either `scope :published_article, -> { where('layout_id = ? AND is_published = ?', ENV['ARTICLE_LAYOUT_ID'], true) }`. But for some reason this is only happing on staging. Works fine in development

Comment: Well, that was as far as my knowledge could provide.